# Face detection in backlit scenes

Tags: computer-vision

It is known that the Viola Jones face detector performs poorly when there is backlight in the scene. Is there a way to preprocess the image such that VJ will work better? Otherwise, is there any other face detector that does not suffer from the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you expect many such images, you can train your the VJ detector on your own such data set.  Assuming there is actual data in the dark face region and that it isn't just under-saturated, that should help improve the performance.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to achieve an improvement of VJ performance by using [this](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~ctshen/Backlit/Backlit) code for backlight compensation. However, the results are still far the level of performance on well-lit images.